# Python program for fourth largest element in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have written the code but it's showing incorrect output for fourth largest element.Let me know what should I do?

```
test=[4, 6, 9, 4, 3, 88, 3, 2]
test.sort()
print("Original list: ",test)
res=[]
for i in test:
    if i not in res:
             res.append(i)
print("Removing duplicates: ",res)
print("4th largest element: ",test[-4])
```

Comment: you're printing `test[-4]`; it should be `res[-4]`

Comment: `print("Original list: ",test)` doesn't make sense immediately after sorting and hence changing the original list. It isn't the original list anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You are very close you can just use the build in sorted function and get the [-4] index on the return value

```py
test = [4, 6, 9, 4, 3, 88, 3, 2]
fourth = sorted(test)[-4]
print(fourth)
```

To remove duplicates make the `test` a set

```py
test = [4, 6, 9, 4, 3, 88, 3, 2]
fourth = sorted(set(test))[-4]
print(fourth)
```

Comment: This doesn't remove duplicates

Comment: set removes the duplicates

Comment: You are right that set will remove duplicates, but the problem is that there is no protection from an IndexError if there are fewer 4 items left after duplicate removal.

Comment: You can fix that with try catch or another way

Answer (score 1):

Breaking everything down:

```
test=[4, 6, 9, 4, 3, 88, 3, 2] 
test = set(test) # Converting to set to get only unique numbers
test = list(test) # Converting back to list
test.sort(reverse = True) # Sorting in decreasing order
if len(test) >= 4: # Checking whether 4th element exists or not
    print(test[3]) # Printing 4th largest element
else:
    print("Not enough elements")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) like:

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(4, test)[-1]
4
```

For small lists this might be slower than just sorting, but in the general case it should perform better since it does not require sorting the full list.  I haven't tested the performance versus sorting though.